# Loading PDF files into picturebox in VB6

Tags: pdf, vb6, file-conversion

I know that in the "Insertable Objects" tab on the Components window, that there is "Adobe Acrobat Document," but that isn't really what I'm looking for. I'm not sure what the "Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Browser Control Type Library 1.0" (created an error when I tried to use it) is in the "Controls" tab.

Here is the functionality that I need:

- read how many pages are in a PDF file
- import each page as a background into a picturebox

I saw this here on SO regarding converting PDF's to TIFF's, so I'm not sure if this would be the best way to go? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2...rt-pdf-to-tiff ; I downloaded ImageMagick and am not sure how to use it, but I'll be looking into it (not sure whether I have to use "Shell" on ImageMagick's convert.exe or if there is a better way [like using a DLL])

I also saw this: http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/faq/c...age-to-pdf.php

This one looked promising, but it appears to be for .NET: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/For...-c1d98a90a2a2/

I'll be working on this, but anything to point me in the right direction is appreciated and detailed information is greatly appreciated -- maybe even rewarded with a bounty.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a commercial library is an option for you, you could try with [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex/). You could embed it in your application as a viewer, or you could use the method [ExportToJPeg_Method](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_ACTIVE_X/Using_the_PDF_Creator_Control/Methods/Exporting/ExportToJPeg_Method.htm) and load the resulting images in your picturebox instead.

Sample code:

```
On Error GoTo report_error
With PDFCreactiveX1
.Open "test.pdf", ""
'export the PDF file to JPEG format with the resolution=300 and
'compression level=9.
.ExportToJPeg "exportJpeg.jpg", 300, 9
End With
```

You could also [use ImageMagic](http://studio.imagemagick.org/pipermail/magick-users/2002-May/002616.html) for PDF to image conversion by using shell execution:

```
Shell "convert v.pdf v%d.png"
```

Be aware that ImageMagic "PDF to image" conversion requires ghostscript, which is a GPL project, which means that you are not supposed to use it for free in a commercial closed-source application.

*Usual disclaimer applies for the first suggestion*

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I gave QuickPDF a try, and it's taking about 2.5 seconds per page to convert to BMP and 4.1 and 4.6 seconds to convert to JPEG and PNG respectively.  At 150 DPI, the pages are 3600x5400 -- quite large.  Any idea how quickly Amyuni or ImageMagic could do it?

Comment: There is a [benchmark for PDF generation](http://blog.amyuni.com/?p=1679) with Amyuni PDF Converter, Ghostscript and others, but not for images generation from PDF, sorry.

Comment: I'll give Amyuni a shot.  I can't try every single library, so I'm either going to go with QuickPDF or Amyuni.  QuickPDF is cheaper, so Amyuni will have to be at least 10% faster for me to use it, but we shall see.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there is another option, that is if you don't mind writing a com wrapper for a .net module.  It doesn't appear to be all that complicated, but may not be worth the time to you.  Anyways it is called [ItextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/), and sadly, no one has posted the com wrappers for download, but the MSDN has how-to guides on writing them.  I hope this helps.

Sources:
-Personal Experience involving PDF files and VB6.

Comment: -1 iTextSharp CANNOT be used for rendering PDF files in the screen, or converting them into an image.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs to preview it, you can use this code snippet:

```
ShellExecute Me.hWnd, vbNullString, "c:\MyPDFFile.pdf", vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
```